# Does youtube-dl still work(newest version youtube-dl-2020.2.16)?

Tags: youtube-dl

Used command:

```
youtube-dl --max-filesize 30m -f m4a -o "/home/dc3014b3c6a1a23bba88b2a1fbcc1447.m4a" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Xa0ydtx8PM"
```

youtube-dl can't work at all for me. Error happened like these:

```
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:618)> (caused by URLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:618)'),))
```

OR

```
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

But When I use curl command to get url content, it's ok.

```
curl -v https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Xa0ydtx8PM
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, You might want to be sure you are using the latest version of youtube-dl. you might want to update it. Am assuming you are using a *nix system. Also depending on how you first installed, there are several options for updating. here are a few options;

For manual installations:
you can simply run `youtube-dl -U` or, on Linux, `sudo youtube-dl -U`.

If you are already running on an update version, you may want to consider the below as best methods to download videos. Mind you that with the new version of youtube-dl, it automatically downloads the best version for you so you do not need to specify although you could still do this to be sure.

```
# Download best mp4 format available or any other best if no mp4 available
$ youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best'

# Download best format available but no better than 480p
$ youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=480]+bestaudio/best[height<=480]'

# Download best video only format but no bigger than 50 MB
$ youtube-dl -f 'best[filesize<50M]'

# Download best format available via direct link over HTTP/HTTPS protocol
$ youtube-dl -f '(bestvideo+bestaudio/best)[protocol^=http]'

# Download the best video format and the best audio format without merging them
$ youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo,bestaudio' -o '%(title)s.f%(format_id)s.%(ext)s'
```

Here is a link for reference and further instructions/support.

I hope this helps. If not, let me know. Glad to help to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share the youtube-dl *alternative* (it is just a fork) that for now (September 2022) works fine and supports almost all youtube-dl features [**yt-dlp**](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp).
I switched to this project and now I am using the same scripts which I had have previously.